# get center polygon C#

Tags: c#, polygon, point

[image: example problem polygon]

what algorithm that i can use to get the center of polygon (red point)
case 1 : i try with maxX, maxY, minX, minY and i got the wrong point (black point)
case 2 : i try to get the second max and min coordinate X and Y, but i got problem with the polygon which have point less than 5
case 3 : i add `if point count < 5 then use case 1 else use case 2` but i got some error for some polygon


can you tell me the right algorithm for me??

note :
[image: pic 4th]

explaination for 4th picture

```
//ma mean max, mi mean min, X1 mean first, X2 mean second
maX1 = maX2 = maY1 = maY2 = 0;
miX1 = miX2 = miY1 = miY2 = 2000;
//aCoor is array of coordinate, format = {x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,...}
for(int i=0; i<aCoor.count(); i+=2)
{
     //point is list of point
     point.Add(aCoor[i],aCoor[i + 1]);
     //this to get second max X
     if(maX2 < aCoor[i])
     {
         maX2 = aCoor[i];
     //this to get first max x
     if(maX1 < maX2) {maX1 += maX2; maX2 = maX1 - maX2; maX1 -= maX2;}
     }

     //this to get second min X
     if(miX2 > aCoor[i])
     {
         miX2 = aCoor[i];
     //this to get first min x
     if(miX1 > miX2) {miX1 += miX2; miX2 = miX1 - miX2; miX1 -= miX2;}
     }

     //this to get second max Y
     if(maY2 < aCoor[i + 1])
     {
         maY2 = aCoor[i + 1];
     //this to get first max x
     if(maY1 < maY2) {maY1 += maY2; maY2 = maY1 - maY2; maY1 -= maY2;}
     }

     //this to get second min Y
     if(miY2 > aCoor[i + 1])
     {
         miY2 = aCoor[i + 1];
     //this to get first min x
     if(miY1 > miY2) {miY1 += miY2; miY2 = miY1 - miY2; miY1 -= miY2;}
     }
}

if(point.Count < 5)
{
    Xcenter = (maX1 + miX1) / 2;
    Ycenter = (maY1 + miY1) / 2;
}
else
{
    Xcenter = (maX2 + miX2) / 2;
    Ycenter = (maY2 + miY2) / 2;
}
```

this how far i do

Comment: 4th one is not the one polygon, they are two

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is not the geometric center (or [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)) of the polygon, but the center of the portion of the polygon's axis of symmetry which lies inside the polygon. Let me edit one of your examples to demonstrate:

[Edited example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vil7.png)

Do you see what I mean?

I picked this example because it demonstrates another flaw in your thinking; this is two polygons, and each of them produce a point that fits the qualifications you're looking for. In your example you just arbitrarily chose one of them as the point you want. (I have seen your edited fourth example; it still has two interiors and does not change my point.)

In any case, what you're looking for is actually the solution to two problems: first, how to find an axis of symmetry for a polygon; second, finding a line segment on that axis of symmetry which also lies in the interior of the polygon. After that, finding the center of that segment is trivial.

I can't post any more links, but there's a paper by P. Highnam out of Carnegie Mellon University entitled Optimal Algorithms for Finding the Symmetries of a Planar Point Set which could help with the first problem, it's a bit involved so I won't explain it here. The second problem just boils down to testing each line segment to see if it contains a point of intersection with a line along the axis of symmetry running through the figure's centroid. Assuming your polygon only has one interior (read: is not like your fourth example), you should get two points. Average them and you have your center.